# Why I am seeing 120 ohms resistance in obd connector Pin6 amd Pin16 and at ABS connector resistance between can+ and can- shows 60 ohms. Why?

Tags: control, automotive, can

I am seeing a resistance of 120 ohms between CAN high and CAN low at the OBD Connector between pin 6 and pin 14. I also checked the can bus resistance at the ABS/ESP module connector and it shows 60 ohms. How can this be possible?

Comment: They’re probably on different busses. I’d guess the obd connector has a dedicated bus to communicate with diagnostic equipment, or hides behind a can gateway. This would be good practice to prevent anything plugged into the connector from interfering with the operation of the safety-of-life systems. 
Check the vehicle wiring diagram, that would be definitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CAN bus should be terminated at each end with a 120 Ohm resistor. This is placed across the two lines CAN-H and CAH-L. Two parallel 120 ohm resistors will give you 60 ohms which is what you should be reading anywhere on that bus. You did not specify the vehicle, some have a seperate CAN bus for the OBDII connector. Reading 120 ohms probably indicates your system is set up this way. Your test plug should also read about 120 ohms. This configuration allows the OEM to control what information is available to non factory entities and protects critical vehicle systems.